# Remove Facebook login image

Tags: ios, facebook

how can i get rid of this annoying image? It keeps popping up when user will touch my custom Facebook button

[image]

Comment: it is the default one , we can't handle in manually

Comment: It will happen each time you login through fb . But if you want to avoid this then save some session or userdefault containng user id so that you can directly redirect without showing this permission window in browser.